# How to send different url with different profiles in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I have a following code:

```
this.$store.dispatch(GET_RESOURCE,
          // 'http://10.20.48.124:1001/get/data/'  -->this one for dev profile
          // 'http://10.20.48.124:8008/get/data/' -->this one for test profile
          'http://localhost:3000/get/data/'  -->this one for local profile
      );
```

Right now its hardcoded to work only in localhost, but when i will deploy it on dev it won't work. Is there any solution to make it work in any profile? Maybe having some type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by looking at the `NODE_ENV` variable to see which environment uou are in, and changing the url to match. Something like:

```
let baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/devapi/1/api/'
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  baseURL = 'https://example.com/api/v1/api/'
}

this.$store.dispatch(GET_RESOURCE, baseURL)
```

By default there are `development` and `production` environments. If you want to create more, e.g for `test` - create a file in the project root with the filename `.env.test` containing:

```
NODE_ENV=test
```

You can then run your npm commnds in the different environments - for example for `vue-cli-service` you can add `--mode test`

Comment: Can I create also NODE_ENV for local development?

Comment: Yes - just repeat the steps shown but replace `test` in the filename/contents with `local` or any other word you like.

Answer (score 1):

All you are looking for is the `dotenv` for Vue. You can refer to the [Official guide](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html) which explains how you can switch between environment variables in different environments (i.e. development, production, etc). Basically, you need to create `.env`, `.env.development`, `.env.production` etc files and keep your variables there. The rest of the things will be taken care of automatically. If there is a predefined way, there is no need to re-invent the wheel by checking `NODE_ENV` everytime you want to switch between environment variables.